# PyMC sampling ignores the bounds of a parameter

Tags: python, sampling, pymc, mcmc

I want to use slice sampling in PyMC2. I have a custom log_likelihood function, and a model with 4 uniform parameters with upper and lower bounds.

When I run sampling, PyMC ignores the parameter bounds and generates values outside of the bounds.

I wrote a simple example of this:

```
import pymc as pm
X = pm.Uniform('X', 0, 1, value=0.45)

@pm.potential
def log_l(X=X):
    print 'X = ',X
    logp = -X**2 / 5.
    print 'logp = ',logp
    return logp


m = pm.MCMC([X, log_l])
m.use_step_method(pm.Slicer, X)
m.sample(iter=1)
```

Example output:

```
X =  -0.0287598536765
logp =  -0.000165425836698
X =  -1.02875985368
logp =  -0.211669367307
X =  -2.02875985368
logp =  -0.823173308778
X =  0.971240146324
logp =  -0.188661484366
X =  1.97124014632
logp =  -0.777157542896
X =  -0.157629460676
logp =  -0.00496940937459
```

So the sampling generates values of X that are negative, despite the fact that the uniform prior specifies a lower bound of 0.

Does anyone have any intuition as to why this is happening?